# HTTP_REFERER empty when redirected by Auth Component

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP when you try to access a protect action you are automatically taken to the login form within your app. However the HTTP_REFERER is empty????

```
$referer = env('HTTP_REFERER');

echo $referer;
```

So normally when I visit the login page I will see the previous page URL with this code displayed, but if I visit the login page after being taken there by the Auth Component then it will be empty...

why is it empty? as I was just referred???

and how do I get it to acknowledge the redirect as a referal? **NOTE: Using the Auth.Redirect session value is not an option in this case because it will stay around after the person has left the site, so for example if they return to the login page it will show the ORIGINAL requested action and NOT the referred page! So it will act as a referral even when its not because it's using the existing session**

EDIT:

As an alternate example:

```
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'their was no referer';
    }
```

When the user is taken to the login form it will say their was no referer but that's obviously not TRUE! ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_REFERER` is a way of the browser to tell the server what page the user was visiting before. It does not signal what page the user has just been redirected from.

Take for example the Ads on Stackoverflow here. Clicking on one of them will take you to some long URL at `adzerk.net`, which records your click and then redirects you to the target URL. The intermediate Adzerk page is not an interesting page in itself and the user is never actually seeing it, unless he's paying close attention to the address bar. In fact there isn't even a "page" there. So it doesn't count as a "page visit". The next page will receive `stackoverflow.com` as the referer, the intermediate redirect page is irrelevant.

```
Stackoverflow -> Adzerk redirect -> Some advertiser
                                    HTTP_REFERER: stackoverflow.com
```

There's also no referer at all if you type an address into the address bar. If you're on Stackoverflow and *type* `yahoo.com` into the address bar, Yahoo will not see any referer from you. If you *click* on a link that takes you from Stackoverflow to Yahoo, the browser does send a referer.

In your case, if you directly access a protected action by typing it in the address bar and get redirected, there simply is no previous page you came from.

---

As per the comments, here how to inject data into the URL while redirecting:

```
AppController extends Controller {

    function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
        if (is_array($url)) {
            $url['?'] = 'redirect=true';
        } else {
            $url.= '?redirect=true';
        }
        return parent::redirect($url, $status, $exit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay that all being said. How would I know that the user had been redirected then if no referer is set? I can't just check for the existence of the Auth.Redirect session because that could also exist if the user visits the login page directly.... So how do I tell the difference? Thanks

Comment: HTTP is tricky, isn't it. :) The answer is, you can't really do these things easily implicitly. If you need to track such information, explicitly embed them in the URL, like a `?redirect=true` parameter or something. You can override `AppController::redirect` to inject that parameter. Overall you might want to embrace a more stateless design though instead of fighting how HTTP works and accept that some things just can't/shouldn't be done. At least that's what springs to mind seeing your recent questions. :)

Comment: I'd love to use query strings instead of sessions for this stuff but for some reason CakePHP just blew up and complained about redirect loops all the time :/ Not to mention that I'd just end up in the same problem as how do I pass the query of the redirection if the Auth.redirect isn't classed as referer :P same issue really.

Comment: could you show an example of this override to inject the parameter in the url

Comment: If the user access a protected action though and is sent to the login form will that query string be added? (can't test at the moment) If not then we still have the issue of not being able to detect a redirect from the auth component...

Comment: @Cameron Yes, it will be attached in case of a redirect through the AuthComponent.

Comment: @Cameron And as I keep hinting at you, I think you're just overdoing things in a way not really suited for a web app. But suit yourself. :P

Comment: I actually ended up using another session instead of adding the redirect query string and then deleting it on access to the login form  after checking it exists. Works perfectly :P so I now have 3 sessions to have the ultimate login form that detects when and where the user was and is going to :D

Answer (score 0):

Is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` also empty?

If it is empty it is not set by the server, this means normally there was no referer, you did a simple refresh or called this page via bookmark. See some use cases for referer here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/

Comment: Yes it's empty. Any ideas why though? As the user reached that page by being sent from the other so it should contain something!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the refer controller?

`$refer = 
Controller::referer(); // referral url`